# c# lock() hangs on second lock attempt

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

**EDIT2-->**
Take a look at the bottom;
**<--EDIT2**

I encountered wierd (to me, at least) behaviour.

I even created simple WinForms class and simple class (code below) to test it.

I always thought that calling `lock(m_lock)` if previous `lock(m_lock)` call didn't ended, the first one will wait and enter onece the second leaves the scope of lock. Nope.

Flow of actions is:

1. Create `Class1` object;
2. Call `Start()` method;
3. Call `DoSomething()` method while `m_lock` is locked in `run` method;

Output is:

> start()
>
> Trying to acquire lock
>
> Acquired lock
>
> Released lock
>
> Trying to acquire lock
>
> Acquired lock
>
> DoSomething() Trying to acquire lock
>
> ... hangs ...

What am I missing or doing wrong? I'm a new one to C# (came from C++) so maybe there are some *gotchas* in C#.

And it still hangs... (by the time I ended writing this post)

**EDIT-->**
In a real world I use lock to secure read/write/configure on serialPort (with synchroneous read/writes, not async ones). And I see in dbg that there are some internal `WaitOne` calls. Don't know if it is relevant.
**<--EDIT**

Here's example:

```
using System;

namespace LockTester
{
    public class Class1
    {
        object m_lock = null;
        bool m_isRunning;
        System.Threading.Thread m_thread = null;
        public Class1()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Class1 ctor");
            m_lock = new object();
            m_isRunning = false;
        }
    
        public void DoSomething(){
            Console.WriteLine("DoSomething() Trying to acquire lock");
            lock(m_lock){
                Console.WriteLine("DoSomething() Acquired lock");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("DoSomething() Released lock");
        }
    
        public void Start(){
            Console.WriteLine("start()");
            m_isRunning = true;
            if (m_thread == null){
                m_thread = new System.Threading.Thread(Run);
            }
            m_thread.Start();
        }
    
        public void Stop(){
            Console.WriteLine("stop()");
            m_isRunning = false;
        }
    
        private void Run(){
            while (m_isRunning){
                Console.WriteLine("Trying to acquire lock");
                lock(m_lock){
                    Console.WriteLine("Acquired lock");
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Released lock");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Ok, found the answer. It was in one more common denominator.

I have found somewhere (SO probably) a solution to redirect Console output to TextBox (for purely testing reasons, you know - small testing applications with gui, which can capture tested object's internal messages being printed to Console).

Here's the code:

used in my form's constructor with :

`_writer = new TextBoxStreamWriter(textBox1, this);`

`Console.SetOut(_writer);`

```
public class TextBoxStreamWriter : TextWriter
{
    TextBox _output = null;
    Form _form = null;
    object _lock = new object();
    
    delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);
    
    private void SetText(string text)
    {
      // InvokeRequired required compares the thread ID of the
      // calling thread to the thread ID of the creating thread.
      // If these threads are different, it returns true.
      if (_output.InvokeRequired)
      { 
        SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
        _form.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
      }
      else
      {
          _output.AppendText(text);
      }
    }
    
    
    public TextBoxStreamWriter(TextBox output, Form form)
    {
        _output = output;
        _form = form;
    }

    public override void Write(char value)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            base.Write(value);
            SetText(value.ToString());
        }
    }

    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
        get { return System.Text.Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

Anyone can explain me why this caused this problem?

Comment: Based on your edit, it seems your serial I/O code inside one of the lock blocks is stalled. Why it is stalled is hard to guess without seeing the actual code...

Comment: This code runs perfectly for me.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead - so is it platform/configuration specific? I run it with Target Framework of 4.0CP but the 'real one' goes to 3.5... Equal denominator here is my machine.

Comment: Nope.. platform changes don't seem to make a difference for me.

Comment: One thing to watch out for is that for an STA thread, the message queue is pumped by `Monitor.Enter()`, which is used to implement `lock`. This can cause deadlocks. Can you try changing your app's main thread to `[MTAThread]` to see if it makes any difference?

Comment: Changing `ApartmentState` to `MTA` didn't fixed that (the way that someone posted, but post disappeared).

Comment: It hangs because of `Invoke`, which will post a message to the input queue for the form, then wait for that message to be processed. If the thread that owns the form is blocked, it will not process messages.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen can you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: I'm having a hard time telling what your question is about: redirecting console output, locking inefficiencies, or something else all together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call [Form.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.invoke.aspx), it will do this:

> Executes the specified delegate on the thread that owns the control's underlying window handle.

The way it does this is to post a message into the message queue of the owning thread, and wait for that thread to process the message.

As such, `Invoke` is a *blocking* call that does not return until the invoked delegate has been called.

Now, the likely reason your code is blocking is that your main GUI thread is already waiting for something else to happen, likely that your external program has completed.

As such it is not actually processing messages.

If this is the reason, then the solution here is to remove the blocking part of the GUI thread. Don't sit around waiting for the external program to complete, instead spin out a task that waits for it to complete and then raises appropriate events on the main form when it does. In the mean time, the main thread is free to process messages, update textboxes, etc.

Note that this means that if starting the external program is done in response to an event, like a button click, you may need to disable parts of the user interface while the program is running, to avoid having the user click the button twice, starting two parallel executions that will both report to the same textbox.

Conclusion: Multithreaded programming is hard!